# New C++ coder w/difficulty on scope/visibility in queue example

Tags: c++

All,

I asked a question last week and I thank you for your tolerance in answering. I'm overall an inexperienced coder but have dabbled most of my life. This is the hardest language/class I've ever taken and it's driving me nuts that I can't get some of these concepts. I've done quite a bit of googling and found some helpful things but never something quite similar enough to fix what I've run into.

ALSO: I am not that familiar with the SO interface, so wasn't sure last time how to 'mark' an answer as the best to give credit to those who helped. I didn't see a way to respond to other smaller comments. A lot in here, but I want to do the right thing for you folks taking the time to help others.

The assignment is to create a queue class with five files described as follows:

**QueueItem.h** contains the class definition for QueueItem

**QueueItem.cpp** contains the member function implementations for QueueItem.

**Queue.h** contains the class definition for Queue.

**Queue.cpp** contains the member function implementations for Queue.

**main.cpp** contains the main() test function.

Queue.h

```
#pragma once

#include "QueueItem.h"

class Queue {
public:
    Queue();    // ctor inits a new empty Queue
    ~Queue();   // dtor erases any remaining QueueItems
    void addItem(const char* pData);
    void removeItem();
    void print();
    void erase();

private:
    QueueItem* _pHead; // always points to first QueueItem in the list
    QueueItem* _pTail; // always points to the last QueueItem in the list
    int _itemCounter;  // always increasing for a unique id to assign to each new QueueItem
};
```

In Queue.cpp below, there are two places where I think the code should either be _pTail->_pNext or _pTail._pNext. If it's the ->, then I get **C++ member (declared at line 21 of) is inaccessible** but using the . gives **C++ expression must have class type**. This is definitely one of the places where I think it's a conceptual thing I'm not understanding because I think it should be the -> but have no idea how to make that accessible.

Queue.cpp

```
#include "Queue.h"
#include "QueueItem.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Queue::addItem(const char* pData) {

    // dynamically create and init a new QueueItem object
    QueueItem* pItem = new QueueItem(pData, ++_itemCounter);

    if (0 == _pHead)  // check for empty queue
        _pHead = _pTail = pItem;

    else {
        // link new item onto tail of list using _pTail pointer
        _pTail->_pNext = pItem; // links the current pTail to the new pItem
        _pTail = pItem; // move the pTail to the new item
    }
}

void Queue::removeItem() {

    // check for empty queue
    if (0 == _pHead)
    { // if empty, nothing to do
    }
    else
    {
        // pop top item off
        QueueItem* popped = _pHead; // create popped to hold value of _pHead
        _pHead = popped->_pNext; // Move the pHead to the next in queue
        delete popped; // delete the popped value
        --_itemCounter; // decrement counter

    }
}
```

QueueItem.h

```
#pragma once

#include "Queue.h"



class QueueItem {
public:
    QueueItem(const char* pData, int id); // ctor
    void setNext(QueueItem* pItem);
    QueueItem* getNext() const;
    int getId() const;
    const char* getData() const;

private:
    char _data[30];    // data value (null terminated character string)
    const int _itemId; // unique id for item in queue
    QueueItem* _pNext; // next item in queue
};
```

In QueueItem.cpp below, the ctor is not right. The error **C++ no instance of overloaded function matches the specified type** comes up and I'm not sure why. It seems like the call matches the definition?

QueueItem.cpp

```
#include "QueueItem.h"
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

    QueueItem::QueueItem(char* pData, int id) // ctor
     : _itemId{ id } // Initialization list
{
     strcpy_s(_data, pData);
     _pNext = NULL;
}

void QueueItem::setNext(QueueItem* pItem)
{
     _pNext = pItem;
}
QueueItem* QueueItem::getNext() const
{
     return _pNext;
}
int QueueItem::getId() const
{
     return _itemId;
}
const char* QueueItem::getData() const
{
     return _data;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "Queue.h"

using namespace std;


  // note - you may need to change the definition of the main function to 
  // be consistent with what your C++ compiler expects. 
int main() {

    char anykey;

    Queue myQueue;

    myQueue.removeItem();
    myQueue.addItem("red");
    myQueue.addItem("green");
    myQueue.addItem("blue");
    myQueue.addItem("orange");
    myQueue.print();  // print contents of queue (item ID and data)
    myQueue.removeItem();
    myQueue.removeItem();
    myQueue.removeItem();
    myQueue.removeItem();
    myQueue.print();
    myQueue.erase();
    myQueue.addItem("olive");
    myQueue.addItem("mauve");
    myQueue.addItem("purple");
    myQueue.print();
    myQueue.erase();
    myQueue.print();

    cout << "Press any key...";
    anykey = getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `QueueItem.h` includes `Queue.h` and vice versa. You cannot have such a cyclic dependency, but `QueueItem.h` doesn't need `Queue`, so you can safely remove the include from there. If this doesn't solve your issue, please copy and paste full error message.

Comment: please include the compiler error message in the question. Don't summarize or paraphrase it

Comment: Problem 1: the `QueueItem::getNext` and `QueueItem::setNext` functions exist for a reason. Problem 2: compare the parameters of the declaration and definition of the constructor more carefully.

Comment: It's been 40 years and I still can't find the any key.

Comment: Right, the cyclic include is one thing, but the error you mention is likely a result of a mismatch between declaration and definition. In `QueueItem.h` you declare constructor as `QueueItem(const char* pData, int id);`, but in `QueueItem.cpp` you define a different constructor: `QueueItem::QueueItem(char* pData, int id)`

Comment: Yes, that should be `QueueItem::QueueItem(const char* pData, int id)`

Comment: Thank you Yksisarvinen and Paul Sanders. I've gotten rid of the errors and am proceeding with my coding.

 idclev 463035818 - I had not yet attempted to compile. I am using VS2019 and the errors/issues I posted about were from the IDE pointing out issues as it detected them before compiling.

molbdnilo - thank you. Valid points, and I def shall heed them.

user4581301 - happy to provide you an opportunity to exercise your sense of humor(?) 

So....how do I mark one of you as giving the answer to give you credit?

Comment: [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) - but you should give the commenters and everyone else a chance to answer before deciding which to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's walk through this in order.

1. **Queue.h**

   ```
    #pragma once

    #include "QueueItem.h"
   ```

   You don't actually use the definition of the `QueueItem` in this header, you only mention pointers to it. To have a pointer to a type (without ever dereferencing it - in the header, that is) - we just need to know the type exists.

   So, you can replace the include with the forward declaration

   ```
    class QueueItem;
   ```

   And break the cycle between the two header files. (You will now need to include `QueueItem.h` in `Queue.cpp` though, because you actually do use it there).

   You actually don't need to include `Queue.h` in `QueueItem.h` either, because it isn't used at all.
2. > In Queue.cpp below, there are two places where I think the code should either be `_pTail->_pNext` or `_pTail._pNext`.

   Yep, your first thought was correct.

   > If it's the ->, then I get `C++ member (declared at line 21 of) is inaccessible`

   The word "inaccessible" tells us that the problem with `_pTail->_pNext` is that `QueueItem::_pNext` is declared `private`. Only methods of the `QueueItem` class (or friends) itself are allowed to access its `private` members.

   You *could* add a `friend` declaration to `QueueItem` to let `Queue` have privileged access to its private parts. But, as you already have a `public` accessor, you can just write `_pTail->getNext()` instead.

   > but using the . `gives C++ expression must have class type`.

   This is because only class (and struct, and union) objects have members. You have a pointer to a class object, so `->` is the right choice. If it helps to remember, `p->member` is essentially the same as `(*p).member` ... it's just nicer to type.
3. > In `QueueItem.cpp` below, the ctor is not right. The error C++ `no instance of overloaded function matches the specified type` comes up and I'm not sure why. It seems like the call matches the definition?

   These two are not the same:

   ```
               QueueItem(const char* pData, int id);
    QueueItem::QueueItem(      char* pData, int id) { ... }
   ```

   I try to just copy & paste lines like this where possible - there's no benefit in doing more typing, with more opportunity for mistakes, and it's sometimes hard to see these simple errors when you know what you intended to write.

Comment: Umm, wow. Thank you so much for your time in actually explaining All The Things. It helped immensely. 

And yes, copy/pasting those strings next to each other to see the differences is really a habit I need to get into.

Comment: I actually meant pasting `QueueItem(const char* pData, int id);` into the cpp file, and then editing it into the right form (adding `QueueItem::` at the start, removing the `;`, etc.) instead of typing it out twice in the first place. A good IDE may help you with this, but there's no need to do extra work even if you're using a plain text editor.

Comment: Ah, yeah, makes sense. Less chance of making an error